# Join table with different primary key values

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to join two tables with different primary key values as below

Table A

```
id     name
1      John
2      Smith
```

and Table B

```
id     name
1-x    Foo
2-x    Bar
```

I've tried using LIKE statements on my query but it won't stop executing.

```
SELECT * FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.id LIKE b.id +'%'
```

Is there any efficient way to JOIN these two tables?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM A a JOIN
     B b
     ON a.id || '-x' = b.id;
```

Then SQLite should be able to use an index on `B(id)` for the query.  It is worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no efficient way of joining them.

That doesn't mean it cannot be done (it can), but it probably doesn't make sense.

Primary keys are not supposed to be good looking or sexy. They are unique row identifiers. If you have a primary key with a value like that, it's because you probably want to expose it or display it somewhere; and that's not their goal.

If you need a nice looking row identifier I suggest you create a secondary unique column that could even be auto-generated.

Bottom line, keep the primary key *simple*.

Comment: yeah, I think one way to do it is by creating a temporary column with substring